# Changing the setter definition of a double field does not reflect

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate

My table structure is as follows:

### Oracle DB Table structure

```
Student
{
    STUDENT_ID varchar2(50) primary key,
    NAME varchar2(50) not null,
    MARKS number(30,8) not null
}
```

### Student.java

```
class Student
{
    private String studentId;
    private String name;
    private double marks;

    /** getters and setters of studentId and name are written over here **/

    public double getMarks()
    {
        return marks;
    }

    public void setMarks(double marks)
    {
        this.marks = new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(marks)).setScale(6, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP).doubleValue();
    }
}
```

### Hibernate Mapping

```
<class name="com.example.bo.Student" table="Student">
    <id name="studentId" column="STUDENT_ID">
        <generator class="uuid" >
            <param name="separator">-</param>
        </generator>
    </id>
    <property name="name" column="NAME" />
    <property name="marks" column="MARKS"/>
</class>
```

- The above code works fine. But for some reason i want to remove the rounding function and simply keep it as follows:

  ```
  public void setMarks(double marks)
  {
      this.marks = marks;
  }
  ```
- But the above change does not work and the previous setter definition gets executed.
- Also I tried changing the variable name "marks" and its getter and setters, but still the previous setter function gets executed.
- Then I created a new column with the later setter definition, the new column works as expected, but the original column "marks" still rounds the value to 6 decimal places.

Comment: Maybe you need to redeploy your application

Comment: The first thing i did was clean, build and redeploy my application.